# HTML5 Canvas: Image crops when x and y values are greater than its width and height

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, coordinates

I'm making a dungeon crawler on canvas. When you move the monsters as well. Skeletons make a square movement.

```
    function enemymove(){
    if(enemyreturn==0){
        if(enemyx<tilesize*3){
            enemyx+=1;
        }
        else{
            if(enemyy<tilesize*3){
                enemyy+=1;
            }
            else{
                enemyreturn=1;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if(enemyx>0){
            enemyx-=1;
        }
        else{
            if(enemyy>0){
                enemyy-=1;
            }
            else{
                enemyreturn=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

tilesize is the default size for each square. 
It all sums up in the positioning code: 
`skeltal.x=(tilesize*j)+tilex+enemyx;
skeltal.y=(tilesize*i)+tiley+enemyy;`

tilex and tiley is the value to move the map. i and j means it's inside a "for loop".
Here are some screens.
[Skeleton normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWQLF.png)

[skeleton starts hiding when x value is increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md9f1.png)

[almost hidden][3]